# Python "\n" tag extra line

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to build a simple board in command line.

**Problem:**
When i use "\n" for ending current line, it adds an extra blank line. How can i fix that?

**Code:**

```
def drawBoard():
    board = [ [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,3,2,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
            ]
    return board

def printBoard():
    for i in drawBoard():
        for a in i:
            print a,
        print "\n"

printBoard()
```

**Output:**

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 3 2 1 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `join()`, don't rely on the `,`  for formatting, and also `print` automatically puts the cursor on a newline every time, so no need of adding another `'\n'` in your `print`.

```
In [24]: for x in board:
    print " ".join(map(str,x))
   ....:     
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 3 2 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
    print "\n"
```

is printing out two `\n` characters -- the one you tell it to, and the one that Python prints out at the end of any line which doesn't end with a `,` like you use in `print a,`.  Simply use

```
    print
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

The print function in python adds itself \n

You could use

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(a)
```

instead

Comment: You can also just print an empty string if you don't want to use sys.stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Add , after the print "\n" line

so that it reads print "\n",